# How to modify the class names of socialmedia module

Tags: theming

I am using social media module. When I inspect the page in chrome, I see some div classes. My css is conflicting with module css classes. I was thinking to modify module's div classes. I was looking for the tpl file inside social media folder but I could not find it.

[image]
[image]

Which file in social media module has the div classes so I can modify the div classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/81kbx4f4/, if you do an inspect element, you will see them here too.

Those are added by facebook and it's not something that you can control.